# NPNFuncs.requestread(stream, rangeList)

Tags: npapi

I have developed a plugin via Firebreath. I need to get range requests to work seeing that I am loading a large file from the server. I would like to specify the range.

For some reason, NPNFuncs.requestread(stream, rangeList) is returning a general error. Does anyone know how to debug this further?

For Firefox, the plugin-container.exe is managing my plugin. Can I build plugin-container as debuggable build from Mozilla and debug it that way?

Thanks,
Scott.